# Powerbi - Published app isn't visible to customer

Tags: powerbi

I'm beginning with Powerbi and published my first app.

My account is pro trial. After published the app I sended an invite to a test customer (  with an e-mail from outside my company ) . This customer then created a new account with the e-mail that I used, installed powerbi but he can't see the app that I have shared with him. He can access only the demo apps installed with the default Powerbi app.

Any toughts ?

Thank you

Comment: The test customer will need a pro license as well. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, could be.My test customer don't have a pro licence.

Comment: Now the test customer owns a pro trial licence but nothing happens

Comment: @AlexisOlson This could be a problem with the Workspace as well. He could have published in a Workspace where the customer is not a part of & therefore the customer won't have the permission to see or even view the dashboard with errors. They can contact their Office365 Admin and get this problem fixed. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your customer needs a pro PowerBi account in order to access to shared reports and shared workspaces.